# how to get child class variable back into parent class in ruby

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance

I would like to create a base class to handle all the methods. How would I achieve this using ruby in this scenario?

```
class Dog
  def initialize
    @breed = "good breed"
  end

  def show_dog
    puts "#{self.class.first_name} of breed #{@breed}"
  end
end

class Lab < Dog

  attr_reader :first_name
  def initialize
    @first_name = "good dog"
  end
end

lb = Lab.new()
lb.show_dog
```

The expected result would be "good dog of breed good breed"
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: with ruby you'd just need to do `first_name` to call the first_name method - it's not like C++ in some cases you need to be explicit about which implemenation of first_name you want to call. self.class.first_name tries to call a class method called first_name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `self.class.first_name` doesn't do what you probably wanted to do. You need to use `@first_name` directly.
2. You need to call the parent class' constructor from the child class; it's not called automatically.

This works:

```
class Dog
  def initialize
    @breed = "good breed"
  end

  def show_dog
    puts "#{@first_name} of breed #{@breed}" ### <- Changed
  end
end

class Lab < Dog

  attr_reader :first_name
  def initialize
    super ### <- Added
    @first_name = "good dog"
  end
end

lb = Lab.new()
lb.show_dog
```

Answer (score 2):

`self.class.first_name` means `Lab.first_name`, not Lab's instance `lb.first_name`